# Trying to get only one tooltip to show on mouseover using d3

Tags: d3.js

I am trying get some tooltips working on my d3 code. I've simplified this code as shown below.

Currently the code produces 6 moving circles with names associated to them, and a console.log shows that when I mouseover over each circle, it's associated name is logged.

Also, when I mouseover a circle, the name labels appear near to the circles. However, the labels appear over *all* of the circles, and I only want a label to appear over the circle that the cursor is hovering over.

I'm not interested in adding a mouseout or anything just yet, just want to get it so that only the hovered over circle gets a label displayed. Any advice on how to do this?

Here is what my code currently looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>

<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var names = ["Jack","Anne","Jacob","Mary","Michael","Lisa"];

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var n = names.length,
    m = 12,
    degrees = 180 / Math.PI;

var bubbles = d3.range(n).map(function() {
  var x = Math.random() * width,
      y = Math.random() * height;
  return {
    vx: Math.random() * 2 - 1,
    vy: Math.random() * 2 - 1,
    path: d3.range(m).map(function() { return [x, y]; }),
    count: 0
  };
});

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var g = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(bubbles)
  .enter().append("g")
  .on("mouseover", function(d,i){console.log(names[i])}); 

  var labels = g.selectAll("text")
        .data(bubbles)
        .enter().append("text")
        .attr("dy",".35em")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("visibility", "hidden")
        .text(function(d,i){return names[i]})

var head = g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(bubbles)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 6)
    .on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
                labels.style("visibility","visible")
                          })

d3.timer(function() {
  for (var i = -1; ++i < n;) {
    var bubble = bubbles[i],
        path = bubble.path,
        dx = bubble.vx,
        dy = bubble.vy,
        x = path[0][0] += dx,
        y = path[0][1] += dy,
        speed = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy),
        count = speed * 10,
        k1 = -5 - speed / 3;

    if (x < 0 || x > width) bubble.vx *= -1;
    if (y < 0 || y > height) bubble.vy *= -1;

      for (var j = 0; ++j < m;) {
      var vx = x - path[j][0],
          vy = y - path[j][1],
          k2 = Math.sin(((bubble.count += count) + j * 3) / 300) / speed;
      path[j][0] = (x += dx / speed * k1) - dy * k2;
      path[j][1] = (y += dy / speed * k1) + dx * k2;
      speed = Math.sqrt((dx = vx) * dx + (dy = vy) * dy);
    }
  }

  labels.attr("transform", labelsTransform);
  head.attr("transform", headTransform);
});

function headTransform(d) {
  return "translate(" + d.path[0] + ")rotate(" + Math.atan2(d.vy, d.vx) * degrees + ")";
}

function labelsTransform(d) {
  return "translate(" + d.path[0]  + ")translate(10)";
}

</script>
<body>

</html>
```

This is my first question on Stack Overflow, so sorry if my question is badly formatted or presented! Any help would be much appreciated, even if it's about how to better present my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)

The issue you're having can be traced back to this section of code:

```
var head = g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(bubbles)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 6)
    .on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
         labels.style("visibility","visible")
    })
```

What this says is that when the user `mouseover`s *any* circle, make *all* labels visible. You probably want something like this

```
    .on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
         // only make visible the current mouseover-ed point
         labels.filter(function(p){
            if(p === d) d3.select(this).style("visibility","visible");
            else d3.select(this).style("visibility","hidden");
         });
    })
```

Comment: Thank you fellow potato! This worked perfectly and makes sense to me.